# How to ignore symbols in SQL LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a search module with SQL query like this:

```
SELECT FROM trilers WHERE title '%something%'
```

And when I search for keyword for example like "spiderman" it returns not found, but when I search for "spider-man" it returns my content (original row in MySQL is "spider-man").

How can I ignore all symbols like `-`, `#`, `!`, `:` and return content with "spiderman" and "spider-man" keywords at the same time?

Comment: You are looking for regular expression search.

Comment: add a column without symbols in your table, and search on it. Otherwise use REGEXP but its slow.

Comment: Cleaning up data before INSERT/UPDATE is half the solution. (Typically done using triggers.)

Comment: This is an interesting question. Which way is better for the resources of the db? Making a tmp result set and manipulating results or doing it on the client side?

Comment: Maybe there is a simpler way than just add another column?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you can do is replace the characters you don't care about before the search takes place.

First iteration would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM  trilers WHERE REPLACE(title, '-', '') LIKE '%spiderman%'
```

This would ignore any '-'.

Next you would rap that with another REPLACE to include '#' like this:

```
SELECT * FROM  trilers WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(title, '-', ''), '#', '') LIKE '%spiderman%'
```

For all 3 ('!','-','#') you would just increase the Replace with another Replace like this:

```
SELECT * FROM  trilers WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(title, '-', ''), '#', ''),'!','') LIKE '%spiderman%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like

`SELECT * FROM trilers WHERE replace(title, '-', '') LIKE '%spiderman%'`

Answer (score 0):

The other answers involving using `REPLACE` are great, but if you don't care what characters appear between "spider" and "man" or how many characters there are between the two strings, you can use an additional wildcard in your expression:

```
SELECT * FROM Superheroes WHERE HeroName LIKE '%spider%man%';
```

If you want to match only *one* character, but allow any character, you can use the [`_` wildcard](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html), which matches only one character:

```
SELECT * FROM Superheroes WHERE HeroName LIKE '%spider_man%';
```

This will match "spideryman" and "spideryman in la la land" but not "spiderysupereliteuberheroman".

If you have a limited number of possible symbols, a way to do it without `REPLACE` is to use a disjunctive expression:

```
SELECT * FROM Superheroes WHERE
    HeroName LIKE '%spiderman%'
OR
    HeroName LIKE '%spider-man%'
OR
    HeroName LIKE '%spider#man%'
OR
    HeroName LIKE '%spider!man%';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE trilers REGEXP '[[:<:]]spider[-#!:]?man[[:>:]]'
```

Some discussion:

```
[[:<:]] -- word boundary
[-#!:]  -- character set, matches any of them.  ('-' must be first)
[-#!:]? -- optional -- so that 'spiderman' will still match
```

This, unlike the rest of the answers, will avoid matching

```
spidermaniac
```

Also, consider using `FULLTEXT`.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use your search with a small update. You should be able to do something like: SELECT FROM trilers WHERE title LIKE '%spider%'. This should search for anything where spider is before or after something else like the hyphen (-)

Comment: But what to do when there are entries like: Spider-man; Spider-Gwent?

Comment: I image you are wanting one query to return the results instead of two, correct?

Comment: Well, what do you as user expect? If you are searching for a Sub-Way Restaurant, you don't wan't a sub station in your results, right?

Comment: That is typically easier, yes. You could try a union that should work.    SELECT FROM trilers WHERE title LIKE 'spiderm%'
  UNION
  SELECT FROM trilers WHERE title LIKE 'spider-m%'